# MongoDB adding data file and restoring DBs

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, restore

My laptop(windows) OS got crashed and manage to get the MongoDB file folder from the D: drive(D:\data\MongoDB\data). In my new laptop(windows) I installed MongoDB and set the data folder path to E: drive(E:\data\MongoDB\data) and copied the data files. And restarted the mongod, but it wants to show the database I was working on. it only shows the default DBS(admin, config, local). How can I restore DBs from data files?

Comment: Did you check the logfile?

Comment: Did you specify the entire path, include the drive?